Issue Integrating Custom Java Maven Library in Mule Flow
I am new to Mule and Anypoint Studio, and I'm trying to integrate a custom Java Maven library project into a Mule flow. I've followed these steps:

Built the custom library project and ensured it is available in my .m2 repository.
Added the dependency of this library into my Mule project POM file.
Cleaned and built the Mule project, confirming the jar is available.
Created a Mule flow and used the "Java New" and "Java Invoke" connectors.
In the class field, I searched for and selected the appropriate Java class, but after selection, I encountered the following error: "Failed to load class with name: Couldn't find class."

After reviewing some blogs, I found that additional dependencies may need to be set under sharedLibraries.
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${mule.maven.plugin.version}</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <classifier>mule-application</classifier>
        <sharedLibraries>
            <sharedLibrary>
                <groupId>ca.fhir.spike</groupId>
                <artifactId>custom-lib</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </sharedLibrary>
        </sharedLibraries>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

However, when I tried this, I encountered another error during the build:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:4.2.0:clean (default-clean) on project abc-api: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:4.2.0:clean for parameter version: Cannot find 'version' in class org.mule.tools.api.classloader.model.SharedLibraryDependency -> [Help 1]

I also attempted to directly add the jar as a third-party jar but faced the same "Couldn't find class" error.
Below are my code snippet:
pom.xml for Java Lib:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ca.fhir.spike</groupId>
    <artifactId>custom-lib</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>
</project>

Java Class:
package ca.fhir.spike;

public class FhirRulesValidation {
    public void validation(){
        System.out.println("Validation Completed");
    }
}

Mule Flow:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:java="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/java" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/java http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/java/current/mule-java.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP Listener config" doc:id="44a7b392-87a9-43bd-8c4b-968564e857c9" >
        <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" />
    </http:listener-config>
    <flow name="java-integrationFlow" doc:id="0b431596-7c6e-48e2-8f1e-6dacf3ac7031" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="71890145-83be-4196-bf30-876abdd69442" path="/validation" allowedMethods="GET" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config"/>
        <java:new doc:name="New" doc:id="331d81e5-28a4-421b-b671-b284f66fb276" class="ca.fhir.spike.FhirRulesValidation" constructor="FhirRulesValidation()" target="resultValidation"/>
        <java:invoke method="validation()" doc:name="Invoke" doc:id="3f42d15a-040d-4d0e-9175-d925a7d74167" instance="resultValidation" class="ca.fhir.spike.FhirRulesValidation"/>
    </flow>
</mule>

pom.xml for Mule Project
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-integration</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>mule-application</packaging>

    <name>java-integration</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <app.runtime>4.7.0</app.runtime>
        <mule.maven.plugin.version>4.2.0</mule.maven.plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <args>-parameters</args>
                    </compilerArgs>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-http-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.3</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-sockets-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-java-module</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.13</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ca.fhir.spike</groupId>
            <artifactId>custom-lib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>anypoint-exchange-v3</id>
            <name>Anypoint Exchange</name>
            <url>https://maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v3/maven</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>

Could you please help me resolve this issue.

Share the complete original error with all lines and formatted as [code block].

The second error is because the shared library configuration should not have a version:
            <sharedLibrary>
                <groupId>ca.fhir.spike</groupId>
                <artifactId>custom-lib</artifactId>
            </sharedLibrary>


Thanks Aled! Build issue is resolved but "Failed to load class with name: Couldn't find class" is still there. There is no error trace. This is the only message I can see in the Anypoint studio on Java Connector.

Where do you see the error? Log or in Studio UI? Add a screenshot to the question if the later.

@JoeLat and at which time do you see the error? Build time, execution time?

you need to export a resources in mule
Ref
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/latest/how-to-export-resources
